# Understanding this version of Fubini's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

The version of Fubini's theorem from my teacher is as below:

> **Theorem.** Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^m,~B\subseteq\Bbb R^m$ be two rectangles, and
>   $C\subseteq A\times B$ be a Jordan region in $\Bbb R^n$. Let $f$ be a
>   function that is integrable on $C$. For $x\in\Bbb R^m$, define
>   $C_x:=\{(x,y)\mid (x,y)\in C\}$. Then
>   $L(x):=\underline{\int}_{C_x}f(x,y)dy$ and
>   $U(x):=\overline{\int}_{C_x}f(x,y)dy$ are all integrable on $A$ and
>   they're both equals to $\int_Cf(x,y)d(x,y).$

Since $C_x$ can be an emptyset, for example when $x$ is at the location in figure. Then does $\underline{\int}_{C_x}f(x,y)dy$ meaningful? Can the region to be integrate be the emptyset? And what is weird is that when I first learned the Fubini's theorem, is Wade's version (similar to what is taught in the introductory calculus courses), which requires every upper/lower limit in the integral sign $\int_{\cdots}^{\cdots}\int_{\cdots}^{\cdots}\cdots\cdots$ exactly fit the region. However, the version of Fubini I just post, seems break down the requirement of fitness, since the outer integral is going to be integrated on $A$, where $A$ can be over-exaggerated, not needing to consider the boundary as fit as possible, just as in my figure. This confuses me.

[image]

Comment: sure, integrating over the empty set gives you what you would hope, zero

Comment: Thanks. For $C:=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$, namely a closed disk in the plane. In this case, can I write $\int_C fd(x,y)=\int_{-100}^{100}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)dydx$? (namely, exaggerate the $x$ range). It seems that the theorem allows us so.

Comment: Definitely not, unless $f$ happends to be zero outside of $C$. Why do you think that the theorem implies this?

Comment: What I first learnt the Fubini's theorem, is Wade's version, which requires every upper/lower limit in the integral sign $\int_{\cdots}^{\cdots}\int_{\cdots}^{\cdots}\cdots\cdots$ exactly fit the region. However, the version of Fubini I just post, seems break down the requirement of fitness, since the outer integral is $\int_A (\cdots\cdots) dx$. And this may allows us to over-exaggerate the region $A$, not needing to consider the boundary as fit as possible.  This confuses me.

Comment: You **could** write $\in_Cf dxdy= \int_{-100}^{100}\int_{-\sqrt{1- x^2}}^{\sqrt{1- x^2}} G(x,y) dyfdx$ where G(x, y) is defined to be f(x,y) as long as (x, y) is inside the circle, $x^2+ y^2\le 1$, and 0 if (x, y) is outside it.